# Composer install in a dockerfile not in entrypoint

Tags: php, docker, symfony, curl, composer-php

For context, I'm trying to build an image of a symfony application with php (fpm), nginx and mysql.

I'm having some trouble trying to run composer install inside a dockerfile and not in an entrypoint.

When I'm doing it from the container itself, the composer install works perfectly but when I try it from the dockerfile, I have two types of error.

For example :

```
Failed to download symfony/twig-bridge from dist: curl error 60 while downloading https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/twig-bridge/zipball/67a33c71062d7d931fe9a8cb7be79cca986a6c09: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

and

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/symfony/web-link.git/': serve
161.6   r certificate verification failed. CAfile: none CRLfile: none
```

I'm running everything with the command `docker compose build --no-cache`.
I just tried everything I found on Google and nothing worked.

**This is my docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  database:
    image: mysql:${MYSQL_VERSION}
    container_name: ${MYSQL_HOST}
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: ${MYSQL_ROOT_USER}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_VERSION: ${MYSQL_VERSION}
    command: ["--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"]
    ports:
      - ${MYSQL_PORT}:3306
    networks:
      - symfony_app
    volumes:
      - app_mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./docker/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf

  php:
    container_name: app-php
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/php/Dockerfile
      target: php_local
      args:
        TIMEZONE: ${TIMEZONE}
        USER_PHP: ${USER_PHP}
        USER_ID: ${USER_ID}
        USER_GROUP_PHP: ${USER_GROUP_PHP}
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/symfony:cached
      - /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt:/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
      - symfony_app_var:/var/www/symfony/var
      - symfony_app_vendor:/var/www/symfony/vendor
    networks:
      - symfony_app
    depends_on:
      - database

  serveur:
    container_name: app-serveur
    build:
      context: ./docker/nginx
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/symfony:cached
      - symfony_app_var:/var/www/symfony/var
      - symfony_app_vendor:/var/www/symfony/vendor
      - /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt:/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
    ports:
      - "8700:80"
    networks:
      - symfony_app
    env_file:
      - ./docker/nginx/.env.nginx.local
    depends_on:
      - php

volumes:
  symfony_app_var:
  symfony_app_vendor:
  app_mysql_data:

networks:
  symfony_app:
```

**And this is my php dockerfile**

```
#syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.4

#Image pour build en environnement local
FROM php:8.2-fpm-buster as php_base

ARG TIMEZONE
ARG USER_PHP
ARG USER_ID
ARG USER_GROUP_PHP

ENV APP_ENV=dev
WORKDIR /var/www/symfony

RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-development" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"
COPY --link ./docker/php/php.ini $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/docker-php-config.ini

# General installation
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    ca-certificates \
    gnupg \
    g++ \
    procps \
    openssl \
    git \
    unzip \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libicu-dev  \
    libonig-dev \
    libxslt1-dev \
    acl \
    && echo 'alias sf="php bin/console"' >> ~/.bashrc

RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-jpeg --with-freetype

RUN docker-php-ext-install \
    pdo pdo_mysql zip xsl gd intl opcache exif mbstring

# Set timezone
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/${TIMEZONE} /etc/localtime && echo ${TIMEZONE} > /etc/timezone \
    && printf '[PHP]\ndate.timezone = "%s"\n', ${TIMEZONE} > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/tzone.ini \
    && "date"

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# exec entrypoint
COPY docker/php/docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-app-entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-app-entrypoint

#Prepare composer installation
COPY --link composer.* symfony.* ./

# Add a non-root user to run the application
RUN groupadd -g ${USER_ID} ${USER_GROUP_PHP} \
    && useradd -u ${USER_ID} -g ${USER_GROUP_PHP} -s /bin/bash -m -d /home/${USER_PHP} ${USER_PHP}

# Default directories + non root user rights
RUN mkdir -p var/cache var/logs var/sessions \
        # Fixes permissions issues in non-dev mode
    && chown -R ${USER_PHP} . var/cache var/logs var/sessions

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-app-entrypoint"]

CMD ["php-fpm"]

# basic image
FROM php_base as php_local

ENV APP_ENV=dev XDEBUG_MODE=off

USER ${USER_PHP}
```

I really need some help on this because I really struggled on this errors... And also, I don't really understand how certificates work on verification.

**EDIT : last update of my Dockerfile, does not work**

```
#syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.4

FROM php:8.2-fpm-buster as php_base

ARG TIMEZONE
ARG USER_PHP
ARG USER_ID
ARG USER_GROUP_PHP

ENV APP_ENV=dev
WORKDIR /var/www/symfony

RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-development" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"
COPY --link ./docker/php/php.ini $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/docker-php-config.ini

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    ca-certificates \
    gnupg \
    g++ \
    procps \
    openssl \
    git \
    unzip \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libicu-dev  \
    libonig-dev \
    libxslt1-dev \
    acl \
    && echo 'alias sf="php bin/console"' >> ~/.bashrc

RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-jpeg --with-freetype

RUN docker-php-ext-install \
    pdo pdo_mysql zip xsl gd intl opcache exif mbstring

COPY --link ./docker/php/cacert.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/cacert.crt
RUN chmod 644 /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/cacert.crt && update-ca-certificates

# Set timezone
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/${TIMEZONE} /etc/localtime && echo ${TIMEZONE} > /etc/timezone \
    && printf '[PHP]\ndate.timezone = "%s"\n', ${TIMEZONE} > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/tzone.ini \
    && "date"

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# exec entrypoint
COPY docker/php/docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-app-entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-app-entrypoint

#Prepare composer installation
COPY --link composer.* symfony.* ./

# Add a non-root user to run the application
RUN groupadd -g ${USER_ID} ${USER_GROUP_PHP} \
    && useradd -u ${USER_ID} -g ${USER_GROUP_PHP} -s /bin/bash -m -d /home/${USER_PHP} ${USER_PHP}

# Default directories + non root user rights
RUN mkdir -p var/cache var/logs var/sessions \
        # Fixes permissions issues in non-dev mode
    && chown -R ${USER_PHP} . var/cache var/logs var/sessions

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-app-entrypoint"]

CMD ["php-fpm"]

#Image pour build en environnement local
FROM php_base as php_local

ENV APP_ENV=dev XDEBUG_MODE=off

RUN composer install --prefer-dist --no-interaction

USER ${USER_PHP}
```

Comment: Oh i see you are indeed installing `ca-certificates` but where are you copying them in your dockerfile? which is why your mount must not be getting them in volumes

Comment: try `COPY /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` in your dockerfile

Comment: I think I have already tried this, Docker told me that /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt does not exist

Comment: Oh can you ssh into the docker and check if `ca-certificates` got installed correctly? Also where it got installed?

Comment: I tried this tonight, and ca-certificates is installed... I edit my first post to add what my last version looks like. I tried to add the cacert.pem by myself and update ca-certificates, does not work...

Comment: I asked a colleague to try from her PC because she's on another network than mine with another proxy. It seems that my problem comes from this as she can composer install normally. I hate company proxies...

Comment: can you check if the SSL Certificates are in the PHP Image? `RUN ls -l /etc/ssl/certs/`

Answer (score -1):

If there are self-signed certs that's your problem with cUrl. Just add --insecure to your cUrl command to tell it to ignore the cert and allow unverified request.

Comment: I'm using composer, so I let him manage his own calls.